# на что заменить Thread.sleep()?

Tags: android, многопоточность, kotlin

Всем привет! Как вставить сюда паузу?

```kotlin
binding.dell.setOnClickListener {
                    input=""
                    binding.inputI.text=""
                   //как вставить сюда паузу? Kotlin .(Theard.sleep() останавливает все действия )
                    binding.dell.visibility = View.INVISIBLE }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если на анроиде, то используйте `postDelayed`:

```
binding.dell.setOnClickListener {
                    input=""
                    binding.inputI.text=""
                    Handler().postDelayed({
                        binding.dell.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: или Timer().schedule

Comment: timer коллбек выполняется в бэкграунд потоке, так что второй вариант приведёт к крэшу, если там изменяется состояние view

Comment: Handler().postDelayed неудачное решение, ибо код продолжает выполняться дальше, а то что в скобках, выполнится позже

Comment: @ArtyMorris но ведь это и требуется...

Comment: @ArtyMorris в котлине есть await?

Comment: Я не знаю, пишу на java

Comment: а я на js) чтоб не блочился интерфейс нужен или колбэк или await

Comment: `postDelayed` это аналог `setInterval` из js, callback добавляется в очередь и будет вызван в UI потоке